# Template directory in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I have a custom dashboard plugin with one of the sections containing useful links. One of them should  directly point to the documentation that comes with a template. This documentation is in the theme directory. Now I've tried different ways to get the path using for example:

```
<?php get_theme_root_uri(); ?>/mytheme/documentation/index.html
```

or

```
<?php get_template_directory_uri() ?>/documentation/index.html
```

but it outputs a URL to the homepage (`http://127.0.0.1/documentation/index.html`) instead of full path to this file. Any advice?

Comment: Don't you want to `echo` that?

Comment: @tf damn.... I behaved like a total noob :/ Really embarrassed. Of course it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you want it to be like that:

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/documentation/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri), `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the *url*, rather than *path*. You want `get_template_directory()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)) or `get_stylesheet_directory()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)).

There is a subtle but important difference between `get_template_directory()` and `get_stylesheet_directory()`. As per the ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)):

> In the case a child theme is being used, the absolute path to the parent theme directory will be returned [by `get_template_directory()`]. Use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get the absolute path to the child theme directory.

Comment: Seems I misinterpreted *"...instead of full path to this file"*.

Comment: I understood it like he wanted to include a link `<a href=...`, that's why I chose `*_uri`. If he wants to _include_ the file etc., then you're right, of course.